# Por que Unity maneja hasta el dato float y no double?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity

Estoy manejando Unity hace poco, y quiero saber por qué Unity maneja, en su mayoría de funciones, coordenadas, funciones de fuerza, y demás valores, el tipo de dato `float`, y no `double`, para lograr mayor precisión en los cálculos?, Es alguna limitación de Hardware actual por parte de los equipos de computo?.

No encontre informacion de esto por internet, o información que responda a mi pregunta.

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es por el formato interno con el que se almacena y manipula el dato. `double` puede manejar mas decimales que `float` pero a costa del *Problema de Doble Redondeo*, cuando prácticamente todo se reduce a un pixel. Por otro lado, el formato de `float` permite optimizaciones para el cálculo de raíces cuadradas, lo cual es esencial en los gráficos por computadora.